# Proper way to inherit UITableViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

My problem is I can't show inherited class from UITableViewController with static cells. I am using storyboard for easy custom cells setup (I want to get a Settings App like behavior) in UITableViewController. But I need to nest it in another UIViewController which shows custom top bar (like navigation bar panel). So when I load my UITableViewController with this structure:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCoolTableVC : UITableViewController

@end
```

I get no issues, all custom cells which I set in storyboard builder are shown in proper way in grouped table view. But when I am using subclass from UITableViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyCoolTableVCSubclass.h"
@interface MyCoolTableVC : MyCoolTableVCSubclass

@end
```

I get this result:

[image]

which shows wild appearance of tableView, without sections and custom cells.
I load my controller with this code, if it helps:

```
UIViewController *vcToGo = nil;
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyCoolStoryboard" bundle:nil] init];
vcToGo = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileTable"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcToGo animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use static cells, the datasource of the table view has to be set to a `UITableViewController` subclass, and you **must not implement the datasource methods yourself**.

The base UITableViewController provides everything to the table view in its own implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  etc, using what you have put in the storyboard. So if your datasource does not inherit from UITableViewController, it will not be able to populate the table.

*(note - This is what I assume is happening based on my own experiments, the internals of UITableViewController are not available to me)*

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that my superclass has overridden datasource methods.